# BUG al cerrar la barra de navegación lateral en flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

actualmente estoy programando con Flutter y mi aplicación funciona de la siguiente forma:

Tengo una pantalla de logueo la cual me lleva a la pagina principal y dentro de esa pantalla tengo una barra de navegacion lateral la cual me permite abrir diferentes fragmentos .

Por ahora usé el metodo WILLPOPSCOPE para que al precionar hacia atrás se cierre la barra de navegacion si es que está abierta y si estoy en un fragmento que no es el principal me manda al mismo (tal como lo hace gmail).

Pero ahora el problema que detecté es que si abro la barra de navegacion lateral , presiono en el espacio en blanco y luego presiono la tecla de back en vez de cumplir la funcion que mencioné antes se va a la pantalla de logueo.

Si pudiera atrapar la accion de tocar en el espacio oscuro que queda libre a la derecha podria solucionar el inconveniente pero no se como hacerlo y no encuentro documentación sobre este caso de uso.

la parte oscura de la derecha es la que presiono y al volver a apretar el back me vuelvo al login.

Muestro un ejemplo de una parte de la pantalla

```
 int _selectedDrawerIndex = 0;
  _getDrawerItemWidget(int pos) {
    switch (pos) {
      case 0:
        return new FirstFragment(value: this.order);
      case 1:
        return new SecondFragment();
      case 2:
        return new ThirdFragment(value: suscribed);
      case 3:
        return new UserProfile();
      case 4:
      //auth.currentUser()==null?print('sin logueo'):print('con logueo');
        signOutWithGoogle().then((e){
          Navigator.of(context).pop(LoginPage.tag);
        });
        break;

      default:
        return new Text("Error");
    }
  }
  _onSelectItem(int index) {
    setState(() => _selectedDrawerIndex = index);
    Navigator.of(context).pop();// close the drawer
    this.draweropen=false;//drawer is closed
  }


  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  _handleDrawer(){
    _key.currentState.openDrawer();
    setState(() {
      print('Actualizando..');
      this.draweropen=true;//drawer is open
      //doAsyncStuff();
    });

  }

  Future<bool> _onWillPop() {
    print(this._selectedDrawerIndex);
    if(this.draweropen==true)
    {
      print('saliendo');
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      this.draweropen=false;
      return null;
    }
    else
    {
      if(this._selectedDrawerIndex==0)
      {
        exit(0);
      }else
      {
        setState(() {
          this._selectedDrawerIndex=0;
        });
      }


      return null;
    }

  }
  Icon actionIcon = new Icon(Icons.search);
  //Widget appBarTitle = new Text("SaleFutbol",style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.color));
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    //print(_currentUserPhotoURL);
    if(photorefresh!=true)
    {
      updatePhoto();
      photorefresh=true;
    }

    //updatePhoto();
    var drawerOptions = <Widget>[];
    for (var i = 0; i < widget.drawerItems.length; i++) {
      var d = widget.drawerItems[i];
      drawerOptions.add(
          new ListTile(
            leading: new Icon(d.icon),
            title: new Text(d.title),
            selected: i == _selectedDrawerIndex,
            onTap: () => _onSelectItem(i),
          )
      );
    }

    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onWillPop,
      child: new
      Scaffold(
          key: _key,
          appBar: new AppBar(
            elevation: 0.0,
            title: Text("SaleFutbol",style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.color)),
            actions: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                      Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.solidBell,color: Colors.white,),
                    ],
                  ),
                  this.notnum>0?Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(height: 13.0),
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                          Material(
                            elevation: 3.0,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(210.0),
                            color: Colors.red,
                            child: Container(
                              height: 20.0,
                              width: 20.0,
                              child: Center(child: Text(this.notnum.toString(),style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ):Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(height: 13.0),
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                          SizedBox(width: 20.0),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),onTap: (){ setState(() {
              this._selectedDrawerIndex=1;
              this.notnum=0;
            });},
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 15.0),
            ],
            leading: new IconButton(icon: new Icon(
              Icons.menu
              ,color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.color,),onPressed:(){
              _handleDrawer();
            }),
          ),
          drawer: new Drawer(
            child: new ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              children: <Widget>[
                new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                  accountName: new Text(_currentUserName), accountEmail: new Text(_currentEmail),currentAccountPicture: GestureDetector(child: Hero(tag: 'UserPH', child: CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: _currentUserPhotoURL==null?AssetImage('images/logo.png'):CachedNetworkImageProvider(_currentUserPhotoURL))),onTap: null,),),
                new Column(children: drawerOptions),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: _getDrawerItemWidget(_selectedDrawerIndex),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, sería ideal si muestras algunas imagenes y un poco de código para entender mejor :)

Comment: ya agregué lo necesario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no quieres retornar a la pantalla anterior (Login) , simplemente retorna `false` en el callback the `WillPopScope` , como ese método retorna un `Future`, tienes que marcar tu método como `async`.

```
     Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {
            print(this._selectedDrawerIndex);
            if(this.draweropen==true)
            {
              print('saliendo');
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              this.draweropen=false;
              return false;
            }
            else
            {
              if(this._selectedDrawerIndex==0)
              {
                exit(0);
              }else
              {
                setState(() {
                  this._selectedDrawerIndex=0;
                });
              }


            }
            return false;
          }
```

**Update**

Ok, viendo lo que necesitas, sería necesario sobreescribir la clase de Scaffold , Drawer y DrawerController, lo cual no es tan sencillo.

Otro approach que puedes seguir es, crear un Custom Widget y mostrarlo al presionar el botón izquierdo en tu `AppBar`:

```
    Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Sample"),
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(PageRouteBuilder<Null>(
                  pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
                      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
                    return AnimatedBuilder(
                        animation: animation,
                        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                          return SlideTransition(
                            position: new Tween<Offset>(
                              begin: const Offset(-1.0, 0.0),
                              end: Offset.zero,
                            ).animate(animation),
                            child: YourMenuWidget(),
                          );
                        });
                  },
                  transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600))),
            ),
          ),
```

Con eso vas a mostrar YourMenuWidget, con animación así como el slider al presionar el botón superior izquierdo, ahí tendrías control total del widget y de los gestos.

Comment: el problema persiste. Por eso quiero saber como atrapar el evento de presionar la parte oscura de la derecha .

Comment: pero si presionas la parte oscura, lo que hace es ocultar el menú lateral no?  que tiene que ver eso con el back button? El back button lo puedes capturar con el WillPopScope y retornar false para que no salga de esa pantalla

Comment: No quiero capturar el back porque eso si lo hace el Willpopscope , quiero capturar cuando se hace click en ese espacio oscuro , porque eso cierra la barra lateral pero en mi código quedaria como abierta y al presionar el back tira el navigation.pop que me saca a la pagina del login. Esa parte de código la puse para que si abris la barra podes cerrarla con la tecla de back .

Comment: Estuve revisando el código fuente de Scaffold y Drawer, y los 2 están muy ligados, el Scaffold escucha al Drawer cuando se presiona la parte oscura y luego de eso, el scaffold esconde el drawer, tendrías que sobreescribir el Scaffold

Comment: Claro aparte es como que el OpenDrawer genera la animacion que muestra y esconde el mismo cuando se presiona en esa parte oscura. Como tendria que hacer eso de sobreescribir el scaffold?

Comment: dame un momento, estoy revisando

Comment: Ok, revisa el código fuente de Scaffold, Drawer y DrawerController, tendrías que hacer un copy paste de esas clases y modificarlo según tus necesidades, está un poco complejo de la forma como está construido ese componente muy dependiente. Voy a actualizar mi respuesta con lo que podrías hacer en lugar de esto

Comment: Dale , graciass diego!!

Comment: Ahí actualicé la respuesta, si quieres usar el gesto de swipe para abrir el widget que uaras tienees que usar un gesturedetector como container de tu scaffold

Comment: sisi , entiendo que es complejo sobreescribir lo demás , pero bueno intenté hacer que funcione lo mejor posible aunque apenas llevo unos meses con Flutter. Mil gracias por tu ayuda!!

Comment: No hay problema, puedes dar como aceptada la respuesta :D